# How to remove the last comma from the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is my current code:

```
n = 15, k = 5
def pattern(n):
    # Write your recursive function here
    if n < 0:
        print(n, end=',')
    else:
        print(n, end=',')
        pattern(n-k)
        print(n, end=',')
pattern(n)
```

How can I remove the last comma from my output: `12,7,2,-3,2,7,12,`?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in any case: the `if` or `else`, first of all you print `n`. So you can always start by printing it. Now we can switch the comma to the start of the printing:

```
n = 15
k = 5
def pattern(n):
    # Write your recursive function here
    print(n, end='')
    if n > 0:
        print(', ', end='') 
        pattern(n-k)
        print(', ' + str(n), end='')
pattern(n)
```

Gives:

```py
15, 10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course Tomerikoos answer does exactly what was requested. Here's a solution with a few other benefits:

```
n = 15; k = 5
def pattern(n):
    if n < 0:
        return [n]
    else:
        return [n] + pattern(n-k) + [n]

print(', '.join(map(str,pattern(n))))
```

Explanation:

- You calculate the items of the sequence, and store them in a list
- Printing is done afterwards:

  - First, the function `str` is mapped over the sequence, generating a sequence of strings.
  - Then, the sequerce is joined together using `str.join` on the comma.

Benefits:

- Separates print and computation code, which lets you do something else entirely with the sequence, once calculated
- Uses str.join, which is one of the most handy functions for displaying stuff
- Uses just one print statement.

A side note; you could use pythons inline if:

```
def pattern(n):
    return [n] if n<0 else [n] + pattern(n-k) + [n]
```